# New State doesn't show anything

Tags: angularjs

I'm using `$stateProvider` to allow different components to control different pages, but I can't seem to get it working with more than one page.

**Here's a plnkr:** http://plnkr.co/edit/PatUnSmPJfqcYqjz5XaA?p=preview

DM_RoutingSetup.js:

```
var app = angular.module('DM', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider) {
    states = [
        {                   // --- This Works ---
            name: 'DM', 
            url: '', 
            component: 'dMcomponent' 
        },{                 // --- This Doesn't ---
            name: 'Config', 
            url: '/config', 
            component: 'configcomponent'}
    ];
    states.forEach(state => $stateProvider.state(state))
})
```

`dMcomponent` is defined in DM_Component.js:

```
angular.module("DM").component("dMcomponent", {
    templateUrl: "DM_View.html",
    controllerAs: "m",
    controller: ['$http', DM_Controller]
})
function DM_Controller($http) {
    var m = this
    m.testDM = "TEST DM"
}
```

`configcomponent` is in Config_Component.js:

```
angular.module("DM").component("configcomponent", {
    templateUrl: "Config_View.html",
    controllerAs: "c",
    controller: ['$http', Config_Controller]
})
function Config_Controller($http) {
    var c = this
    c.test = "Test Config"
}
```

Here's a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/PatUnSmPJfqcYqjz5XaA?p=preview, although it doesn't represent what I'm seeing. On plnkr it says "Not Found".

### **On my local environment, "/config" only shows a blank page.**

There is no trace of my app in the Elements tab. Nor any error in the Console tab.

Comment: Can you mention what do you see on your local environment?

Comment: At the bottom in bold is what I see on my local environment.

Comment: Ok, I don't have much time right now, but here is an alternative. This version is using state name instead of URL. Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/zTkvdztNii3DyAlJspCq?p=preview

Comment: This works on the plnkr, but doesn't work on my local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `href="/config"` instead of `href="#/config"`. Here's a [working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KNwrVNjUTkcXdayWiiri?p=preview) fixing yours. The only change is in the href attribute of the links.

Your links would work is you configured the $location service to use the [HTML5 mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes) instead of the default mode. Beware though, this also requires configuration on the server.